# ES6to5, ES6 Module Transpiler and Babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, brunch, babeljs

What's the difference between this packages? are all doing the same ?

Using brunch here, but not brunch specific question.

http://libraries.io/npm/6to5-brunch

http://libraries.io/npm/es6-module-transpiler-brunch

http://libraries.io/npm/babel-brunch

Comment: How does this question not have to do with brunch?

Comment: [Module Transpiler](http://esnext.github.io/es6-module-transpiler/) is different from [babel](https://babeljs.io/) which is the new name for 6to5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well for one thing, [6to5 was renamed to Babel](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/02/15/not-born-to-die/). This is why you see [6to5-brunch](http://libraries.io/npm/6to5-brunch) releases stop at 3.0.0, and [babel-brunch](http://libraries.io/npm/babel-brunch) releases start at 4.0.0.

[ES6 module transpiler](https://github.com/esnext/es6-module-transpiler) ([initially curated by Square](https://github.com/esnext/es6-module-transpiler#acknowledgements)) development seemed to slow down quite a while ago. The project began migrating developers from esnext development to 6to5 development, effectively [joining forces with 6to5](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/01/12/6to5-esnext/). (This was obviously before 6to5 was renamed to Babel) This is likely why you will the [es6-module-transpiler-brunch](http://libraries.io/npm/es6-module-transpiler-brunch) module is very out of date and no longer actively developed.